# Parsing NSArray that has single value generated from a JSON message

Tags: iphone, ios, json, wcf

I've combed the questions on here hoping to find a similar situation that I am in, but couldn't find one. My question deals with the NSJSONSerialization class in iOS 5, and how to handle parsing a single value returned from the JSONObjectWithData:options:error: method. The JSON data returned is a single value in an array that looks like this:

`[1]`

The data will either be 1 (as seen above) or 0, depending on the logic being done in the web service I'm using. As a side note, the web service is a WCF REST service. In XCode, the debugger displays the following after the deserialized JSON is assigned to a temporary NSArray object:

`po parsedData`

`(NSArray *) $43 = 0x06e2ee70 <__NSCFArray 0x6e2ee70>( 1 )`

When I try to get the value from the array using ObjectAtIndex:, I get this:

`po [parsedData objectAtIndex:0]`

`(id) $44 = 0x06b1dad0 1`

My question is: what is the hex value (`0x06b1dad0`) before the `1`? Maybe a key or index that I am not accessing (I was thinking that I just didn't go far enough into the array to get the real value)? Does it have something to do with how the JSON is formatted? As I've been thinking about it, I have a feeling that the formatting is off.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the actual value that is stored in the JSON message--when I access the element in the array `parsedData` and assign it to a variable, it is returning just the hex value and not `1`.

Casting to NSInteger gives this:

`po (NSInteger)[parsedData objectAtIndex:0]`

`(NSInteger) $45 = 112319184 1`

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. I apologize if this has been addressed elsewhere in the forum.

Thanks.

Comment: The hex value is the address of the object in memory and unrelated to your JSON.

Comment: I suspected that might have been what it was, especially when seeing the data in the debugger. Wasn't totally sure though--thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely that the object is an NSNumber try this:

```
[[parsedData objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Comment: Brilliant! That works nicely: `NSInteger anInt = (NSInteger)[parsedData ObjectAtIndex:0] intValue];` Thank you very much!

Comment: @mamyot0 If you want a `NSInteger`, `NSNumber` also has the `integerValue` method which will return one rather than an `int` (saves you the typecasting).